# Integral too oscillatory

Tags: numerical-integration

Is there any way top make this integral less oscillatory?

```
Quiet@Re[NIntegrate[Log[n Log[n Log[n]]] - 1/(Log[n Log[n Log[n]]]), 
{n, 2, #}]] & /@  Range[2, 100] // ListLinePlot
```

Comment: One way to improve on the error estimates is to incrementally integrate over each successive pair of integers. Then sum the partial results. `Quiet[vals = 
   NIntegrate[
      PowerExpand[Log[n Log[n Log[n]]] - 1/(Log[n Log[n Log[n]]]), 
       Assumptions -> n > 2], {n, #, # + 1}] & /@ Range[2, 100];] sums=Accumulate[vals]`. Now use `sums` in that plot.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau that is great - looks perfect - thank you :)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - could you please write this up as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem actually seems to be caused by the very first pair of integers - (2,3)
This is because there is actually a singularity in the function here:

```
Plot[Log[n Log[n Log[n]]]-1/Log[n Log[n Log[n]]],{n,2,3}]
```

[image]

If we ask Integrate to symbolically evaluate the integral between these bounds, it tells us that is does not converge:

```
Integrate[Log[n Log[n Log[n]]]-1/Log[n Log[n Log[n]]],{n, 2, 3}]
Integrate::idiv: Integral of -(1/Log[n Log[n Log[n]]])+Log[n Log[n Log[n]]] does not converge on {2,3}. >>
```

The rest of the function is smooth so if we perform the entire calculation but starting at 3 rather than 2, we encounter no issues:

```
ListLinePlot[NIntegrate[Log[n Log[n Log[n]]]-1/Log[n Log[n Log[n]]],{n,3,#}]&/@Range[3, 100]]
```

And the result is smooth:

[image]

Comment: Good point, which I managed to miss.

Comment: @Nick I feel a little bit silly that I missed this too! Thanks for the great answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to improve on the error estimates is to incrementally integrate over each successive pair of integers. Then sum the partial results.

```
Quiet[vals = NIntegrate[ PowerExpand[Log[n Log[n Log[n]]] -
  1/(Log[n Log[n Log[n]]]), Assumptions -> n > 2], {n, #, # + 1}] & /@
  Range[2, 100];]

sums = Accumulate[vals]
```

Now use sums in that plot.

```
ListLinePlot[Accumulate[vals]]
```

[image]

I do not know offhand why the error estimates as originally posed are so jittery. I'll ask around if I get a chance.

Comment: this is a great technique - thanks for posting as an answer :)